Creating permanent swapfile acting as virtual RAM
I have made a swap file on my Android device that acts as virtual RAM. But I have an issue where the swap file is reset every time the Android device is reset.
Even though I have made a permanent swap file as shown in the below method, still the swap file is reset after rebooting the Android device. How can I achieve the permanent swap file? Can someone help me?

Create a permanent swap file
dd if=/dev/zero of=/$PREFIX/tmp/swapfile bs=1048576 count=4096
mkswap /$PREFIX/tmp/swapfile
swapon /$PREFIX/tmp/swapfile
chmod 600 /$PREFIX/tmp/swapfile
termux-setup-storage

Create Termux boot directory
mkdir -p ~/.termux/boot/

Create a script for the line below
touch start_swap.sh 

Add in the following line inside the directory created
#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/sh
swapon /$PREFIX/tmp/swapfile

Making the script for swap file executable
chmod +x ~/.termux/boot/start_swap.sh

Set swappiness to 100 and make it persistent:
echo 100 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
echo 'vm.swappiness=100' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf

Stress test the memory
pkg install stress
stress --vm 1 --vm-bytes 3G --vm-hand 0


Just making sure you've seen: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-management On Android, storage isn’t used for swap space like it is on other Linux implementations since frequent writing can cause wear on this memory, and shorten the life of the storage medium.

Why not ZRAM?

So, should I implement the swap file created on ZRAM? instead of directly implementing it on RAM?
